# Is there any other way to feed data to Function App without having to let it connect to database like Cosmos DB in Azure?

Tags: azure

I am concerning on any other way that is able to feed data to my Function App without having to let it connect to database like Cosmos DB in Azure? Those data that are not in Device Twin, just in the Cosmos DB. But I do not want my Function App connect to Cosmos DB.

I am considering Stream Analytics however it is too expensive for me at $80+ per month due to the job have to be run non-stop because the input is from IoT Hub and the data is coming in almost every second.

I also considering Redis Cache but I get that cache is single-threaded server so the performance might get slow if multiple request is sending to cache in short period of time.

So I would like to ask community is there any other options that I can use?

Thank you.

Comment: you have data in cosmosdb and dont want to connect to cosmosdb?

Comment: @Sajeetharan Yes I know it sounds trouble but actually cosmos db is belongs to other architecture and its data coming from other architecture. And now I want to try to decouple between these 2 architecture so...